# How do I edit HTML on WordPress post page?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using WordPress and I've made a number of posts. What file do I need to edit, so the same HTML shows on the bottom of all the posts?

Comment: What theme are you using? What version of wordpress are you using? What color are your underwear?

Comment: It's a custom theme based off twentyten. Running 3.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default name of the template file used to display pages in Wordpress is named `page.php`. It is located in your current theme.

Comment: Are both posts and pages controlled from the same PHP file page.php? I thought pages and posts were two different things.

Comment: @Tim no, posts are controlled by `single.php`

Answer (score 1):

there are so many file wordpress theme structure if you want to edit:

```
(i think you Edit single.php)

page.php  : use for simple page
index.php : use for post page
single.php : use for single post if you want to change ur post setting
similerly footer.php, header.php
```

Comment: Thanks, my confusion right now is the template I have have chosen pulls the posts in and puts them on the homepage. Not understanding how or where the file is doing this?

Comment: i dont understand please explain may be i helf you

Comment: in ur wordpress admin select setting then reading setting ... here you seclect "A static page (select below) " two pages one for simple page and the other for post page ( you have first creat a page must)